# iw "command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)"

Tags: linux, networking

I am using iw 5.4. The problem is that sometimes when I write:

```
/usr/sbin/iw dev wlan0 scan
```

Sometimes an error appears

```
command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)
```

Comment: No other processes interact with "iw"